# Is there a way to tell if a sound is currently playing?

Tags: dart, stagexl

I am using the StageXL package for Sounds.

The problem that I have is that I am trying to mute the sounds that are currently playing. The only way that I could find to resolve this is to update all the Sounds currently playing SoundTransform volume to 0.

This is fine but this requires all SoundChannels to be stored somewhere. And without a completed event or something similar this collection will be ever increasing.

So is there a way to tell when a Sound finishes playing?

Comment: Looking through the stagexl/src/media/implementation I don't see a way to do it. You might have better luck on http://www.stagexl.org/forum.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SoundMixer.soundTransform property to change the global volume as simple as this:

```
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.5);
```

This will change all sounds to half of the volume. Of course you can set it to 0.0 to mute all sounds.